# Worse compiz performance in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz, performance

**I know this question has been asked multiple times before**, but they seem to be like 3-4 years old now and I could not find any associated with Ubuntu 14.04. Also, solutions mentioned there do not really increase Unity performance.

Problem is simple - when I drag windows they are not moving smoothly like they should, they simply do little choppy jumps. Bigger window I drag - bigger lags I have. Problem happens also when I open or close launcher - it's not fading in or out smoothly.

Those are things I have already tried:

- Unchecking "Sync To VBlank" in OpenGL section in ccsm - it increased Unity performance a bit.
- Unchecking "Detect Refresh Rate" in Composite section is ccsm
- Installing newer Nvidia drivers
- Logging into Guest Session  - there everything works just fine.

I have also heard of [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~vanvugt/+archive/ubuntu/compiz) with fixed compiz, but I haven't installed it yet, because I guess 2012 compiz is little bit too old.

My computer specification:

- Intel Core 2 Duo ( 2x 2.8GHz )
- 4 GB RAM
- Nvidia GeForce GT 520
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit

Which I think is not that bad.

Drivers available for me:
[image]

Maybe some of You have this problem too, anyway, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything works fine in the guest session, you can use the following very simple system to get a performant system again:

Go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd> <kbd>User Accounts</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> and add a user with the same name as your current user but with a `2` attached to the end.  In below procedure "User" and "User2" will be used.

Now,

1. Log in as User2
2. Open the file manager
3. Browse to the `/home/user` directory
4. **Copy** (don't move!) all the *files* from Downloads to `/home/user2/Downloads`
5. Check you did a good job.
6. Now delete `/home/user/Downloads`
7. Go back to step 3 and repeat for Documents, Videos, ...
8. In a terminal type the following command: `deluser user --remove-home`

## Done!

Comment: Good idea, but I think I'll use it in finality. :)

Comment: I wonder if it happens also to Gnome, does it?

Comment: The above solution is a generic system that works on any OS: Windows, Linux, ...  It's sometimes easier to just circumvent a problem then to try to solve it.

Comment: That's true. I'm thinking about switching to Gnome, because it uses Mutter instead of Compiz. I heard it's less laggy. I think I'll give it a try when I come home later

Comment: The above system will work for Gnome as well.  If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Sure your answer helped me. I was wondering if performance loses aply to Gnome :)

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding you: I honestly cannot answer that question: I like KISS (Keep It Simply Stupid) so I run plain vanilla Ubuntu with as little extra software as possible and monthly system back-ups and weekly file back-ups...  (Unity, no Gnome), but feel free to [ask another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)... **;-)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22832/discussion-between-fabby-and-jacajack).

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing these exact same symptoms and finally decided to do a little diving into my dotfiles and found the solution by systematic process of elimination.

In my case, it turns out that something had gone wrong with the files stored in my compiz configuration cache.

Simply deleting the directory and relogging solved my graphics issues:

```
$ rm ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
```

the cache will be automatically rebuilt (correctly) upon login.

Comment: Actually my compiz wasn't lagging. It was only stupid illusion when I was moving windows from one screen to the other one - everything is working fine. Sorry for not mentioning it before. Anyway thanks for your time. :)